# How to fix blank line after downloaded in the server or after update your themes/plugins via repository php/js/css files?

Tags: php, server, repository, editor, line

I'm using Dreamweaver C6 as my file editor, I always encounter this problem every time I download a file from the server, after update the theme, and plugins via repository updates.

The files is inserting a another empty line or blank line just like the screenshot below.

[image]

I tried to search this online but I can't find the correct way to stop this problem on my end.

Your help will more helpful if you have any idea how to fix this.

Comment: probably a conversion between windows and *nix. most editors will have  a setting to handle that. ans probably stop using "Dreamweaver" id you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: @rtfm, if I don't use Dreamweaver then what file editor I have to use? I tried to open in the other file editor like Sublime Text, same problem. I think this might be on the the editor settings you said. I'll try to configure the settings maybe this can be fix. Thanks rtfm.